# How to import a .js file into a web worker

Tags: web-worker

I have a web worker in this JS file: https://github.com/nikitavoloboev/try/blob/main/solid/src/gitworker.js

This worker should import a .js file, namely this one:

https://github.com/nikitavoloboev/try/blob/main/solid/src/lg2.js

Doing import like below fails for me:

`importScripts("./lg2.js")`

Is there something else I should do to make the import work?

Comment: `FS error` is not an error caused by the import. That's an error message from emscripten, so it seems like the import has succeeded, but the actual problem here is something else.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this, fixed it:

```
var Module = {
  print: function (text) {
    console.log(text)
  },
  printErr: function (text) {
    console.error(text)
  },
}

importScripts("./lg2.js")

const libgitPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  Module.onRuntimeInitialized = () => {
    resolve(Module)
  }
})

;(async () => {
  const libgit = await libgitPromise

  // do your things with `libgit`
})()
```